Determining the Rao-Cramer Lower Bound for an Unbiased Estimator
I am having trouble solving the following problem from my exam:
Let (X, Y) be a sample from a distribution with density $f(x, y; \theta)=e^{-\theta x-\frac{y}{\theta}}$, where $x>0$, $y>0$ and  $\theta>0$.
Let $\tilde{T_{n}}=a_{n}T_{n}$ be an unbiased estimator of the parameter $\theta^{2}$, where $a_{n}$ is a constant. I need to determine:

Whether $\tilde{T_{n}}$ is the best unbiased estimator.
Whether its variance reaches the Rao-Cramer lower bound.
My attempt:
I am having the most trouble finding Tn, especially calculating $ET_{n}$, where $T_{n}$ is $\hat{\theta}^{2}$. I have correctly calculated $\hat{\theta}^{2}$ as $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} Y_{i}}{\sum_{i = 1}^{n} X_{i}}$. Given that $X_{i}$~$\epsilon(\theta)$ and $Y_{i}$~$\epsilon(\frac{1}{\theta})$, I know that $2\theta\sum_{i= 1}^{n}X_{i}\in\chi_{2n}^{2}$ and $\frac{2}{\theta}\sum_{i= 1}^{n}X_{i}\in\chi_{2n}^{2}$.
Any help in proceeding further would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!


The key is that $X_i$ and $Y_i$ are independent, which makes these calculations straightforward.

Thank you so much.

As mentioned, you have already found that maximum likelihood estimator is given by
$$T_n=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}$$
To compute $E(T_n)$, consider the integral
$$J(a,b)=\int_{[0,\infty]^{2n}} e^{-a\sum{x_i}-b\sum{y_i}}\prod_idx_idy_i=\frac{1}{a^nb^n}$$
Then it holds that
$$E(T_n)=-\frac{\partial}{\partial b}\Bigg|_{b=\theta^{-1}}\int_\theta^\infty da J(a,b)$$
Similarly,
$$E(T_n^2)=-\frac{\partial^2}{\partial b^2}\Bigg|_{b=\theta^{-1}}\int_\theta^\infty da_1\int_{a_1}^\infty da J(a,b)$$
Can you finish the calculations using these hints?

I have trouble finding the Rao-Kramer lower bound, specifically g(theta). Thanks a lot for your help.

The techniques required to compute the Fisher information are very similar to the ones outlined above. Expressing the definition in terms of $J(a,b)$ should help.

Thank you very much.
